# Not sure how to return value from function

Tags: python, return

i have a code which i need to return the values, but i think i am not able to place the `return` statement properly. I need to return the combined list of IP address to calling function in python

```
def call_me ():
  ACCESS_KEY= "XX"
  SECRET_KEY= "XXXX"
  regions = ['us-west-2','eu-central-1','ap-southeast-1']
  for region in regions:
    instance_information = {}
    ip_dict = {}
    client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses().get('Addresses')

    for address in addresses_dict:

        if address.get('InstanceId'):
            instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]
         #   print  instance_information

    dex_dict = client.describe_tags().get('Tags')
    for dex in dex_dict:
        if instance_information.get(dex['ResourceId']):
            instance_information[dex['ResourceId']].append(dex.get('Value'))
    for instance in instance_information:

        if len(instance_information[instance]) == 2:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = instance_information[instance][1]
        else:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = ''
#    print (json.dumps(instance_information,indent=4))
    #print type(instance_information)
    ip_list = [i[0]  for i in instance_information.values()]
    print (ip_list)
```

Now i am not sure where to place the `return ip_list` statement since, this runs in 3 regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `ip_list` before the `for` loop and `extend` it with the list of values from each region:

```
ip_list = []
for region in regions:
    instance_information = {}
    #
    # your code
    #
    ip_list.extend(i[0]  for i in instance_information.values())
    print(ip_list)
return ip_list
```

If you want to keep values from regions in a list of lists, then you can replace the extend line with: `ip_list.append([i[0]  for i in instance_information.values()])`

Comment: i doesn't return the value of the first 2 regions that way , only the last region ip's are returned

Comment: trying out your code , m not able to get it right, having indentation issues

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in where to place the return statement. The issue is that you redefine `ip_list` within each iteration of the `for` loop, so there is no point at which you ever have all the information to return it.

I'm not sure exactly what format you want to return the values in, but perhaps you could define a `combined_ip_list` variable as an empty list before the for loop, append the value of `ip_list` instead of printing it at the end of that loop, then return that value outside the loop.

Comment: yes , exactly sir. i need the `combined_ip_list` of form list . can u help me with the code here , i am unable to do so